# getting parsererror from presumed empty json response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

**EL PROBLEMO**

My JSON returns an associative array that I take elements from and display on the page.  Sometimes one or more of the sub-arrays will be empty, and this is expected behavior.  For those I want nothing displayed on the page.  My problem is that currently anytime one of those sub-arrays is empty, I get a "parsererror".  In my application, you switch between months, and this AJAX call is made when the dropdown selection is changed to a different month.  On months where all the sub-arrays have values, I dont get an error.  I only get it when one or more of the sub-arrays are empty.

**PHP**

first I perform the SQL queries, which I'm leaving out to keep this as short as possible, but these are the 3 resulting arrays:

```
$income = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$expense = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$recurring = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I want to assign those to an array, which I then json_encode:

```
$array = array(
            'income'    => $income,
            'expense'   => $expense,
            'recurring' => $recurring
        );

echo json_encode($array);
```

**AJAX**

This is basically calling the previous php code, then displaying each record from the database in a table.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {action: "display_categories", cur_month:cur_month}
});
request.done(function(response){
    $('#income tbody tr, #expense tbody tr').remove();
        for(var i = 0; i < response.income.length; i++) {
           $('<tr><td id="' + response.income[i].cat_id_PK + '">' +         response.income[i].cat_name + '</td><td id="' + response.income[i].cat_id_PK +
'">&#36;' + response.income[i].cat_amount + '</td></tr>').appendTo("#income");
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < response.expense.length; i++) {        
           $('<tr><td id="' + response.expense[i].cat_id_PK + '">' + response.expense[i].cat_name + '</td><td id="' + response.expense[i].cat_id_PK + '">&#36;' + response.expense[i].cat_amount + '</td></tr>').appendTo("#expense");
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < response.recurring.length; i++) {
           $('<tr><td id="' + response.recurring[i].cat_id_PK + '">' +       response.recurring[i].cat_name + '</td><td id="' + response.recurring[i].cat_id_PK + '">&#36;' + response.recurring[i].cat_amount + '</td></tr>').appendTo("#expense");
        }      
});
request.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus){
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
};
```

**JSON**

Here's an example JSON response with two empty sub-arrays.

```
{
"income": [],
"expense": [],
"recurring": [
    {
        "cat_id_PK": 67,
        "cat_name": "Grooming",
        "cat_amount": "40.00",
        "recur_begin": 1,
        "recur_end": 12
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Use the browser's devtools to see what exactly the server sends back. The NET or Network tab should have that. Open it, redo the request.

Comment: {
    "income": [],
    "expense": [],
    "recurring": [
        {
            "cat_id_PK": 67,
            "cat_name": "Grooming",
            "cat_amount": "40.00",
            "recur_begin": 1,
            "recur_end": 12
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I don't understand the problem... Where does the parse error come from? The response is valid JSON. Is it app logic that can't handle empty arrays?

Comment: I figured it out!  it was the same request.fail block in another function that I had just refactored the other day.  It is also called when this function is called, and this is the first time I've had an empty object called on the first function, so I incorrectly assumed it was this one.  Thank you all for the help, and I apologize for wasting your time!

Comment: I think this is your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590357/getting-parseerror-while-receiving-response-from-json-encode-using-ajax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961044/finding-parse-errors-in-javascript

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Error.html

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of rows you get from sql query result.
if they are greater than 0 then send an extra field as

```
$d['status'] ='OK';
```

if no record exists then send the error handling as

```
$d['status'] ='ERR';
```

so check the status field in the data success

```
dataType: 'json',
  data: you data,
  success: function( data ) {
  if(data.status == "OK"){
    alert('success');

  } else{
    alert('failure');

  }

}
});
```

try like this ,just to test and then use data

Comment: Or you can count the number of rows in JS.

Comment: i've tried using if(response.income.length > 0) { //display stuff; } else {}. For some reason this still gives the parsererror.

Comment: if you have status field then at least you can identify whether the values exist or not.before you start using them

Comment: add an exit after echo

Comment: @hyphen Somehow you know it's a parse error. How? Where does it say that? The browser knows, so you know. Give us all the info.

Comment: from this block: request.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus){
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }); <---yields message: "Request failed: parsererror"

Comment: The `fail()` callback receives 3 arguments: `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. Log `errorThrown` to the console. It should have useful details.